# What design pattern would be suitable for async image processing?

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, architecture

I have an app where user can select bunch of images and apply some backend async processing on them. Typical payload front frontend app looks like this:

```
{
 files: ['tmp.jpg', 'tmp2.jpg'],
 config: {'applyX': true, 'applyY': true},
}
```

Where `applyX`, `applyY` are namespaces for some processing functions. I want pattern to give ability to easily add new functions and unit test it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about architectures for asynchronous processing, then a [pipes-and-filters architecture](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) is appropriate.

If you're asking about how to add new functions, then you're probably looking for a [plug-in architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Plug-in architecture seems ideal for the problem